# Linq to Entities query hitting db twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, sql-server-profiler

I have the following pretty simple linq query querying a linq to entities edmx.

```
(from i in ent.Inspectors select i).OrderBy(s => s.Surname).Skip((page - 1) * count).Take(count).ToList();
```

In Sql Server Profiler I can see that the exact same select query is being sent twice.

Can someone explain why?

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Can you verify that the line of code you're describing isn't being hit twice?

Comment: Are you sure it's *actually* being sent twice? SQL Profiler, by default, will show the same query more than once. Can you show the trace?

Comment: @Craig.  Bingo! Thanks for the reply.  Giving the trace more than a cursory man-glance I could see that one was a BatchStarting and the other was a BatchCompleted. <smacks forehead>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of deffered execution, the results of the query aren't cached locally.  To prevent this, add a call to `ToArray` in the query.

Also, `from i in ent.Inspectors select i` is a no-op; you should write `ent.Inspectors.OrderBy(s => s.Surname)...`.

Comment: Yes, but that's at the end.  If one of the methods before it doesn't get translated by L2E, it can still hit twice.

Comment: All of those methods are known by L2E. Unless there's something **significant** he's not telling us, that should only be one query.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  @Slacks, good point about replacing the from i in ...  If the query was to remain getting everything then I would, but it's just the starting point at the moment. :D

Answer (score 1):

Is ent.Inspectors an IEnumerable containing two items?